# Conditional Where clause alternate

Tags: mysql, xml

I am using xml to display the query result. I have one issue related to my query. Say in the customer table i have an data whose id is not a forigne key in any of the other tables, but still I want to display the data. i a, using left join for this. But the problem is with the other table conditions( Where clause  pr.fActive=1...) due to which the i am not able to display the data which is only there in customer table but not in other table. How it can be done

```
<Table>customer cu</Table>
          <Joins>
            left join customerprogramxref cuprxref on cu.ixcustomer=cuprxref.ixcustomer
            left join tblprogram  pr on cuprxref.ixprogram=pr.ixprogram
            left join programworkpackagexref prwpxref on pr.ixprogram= prwpxref.ixprogram
            left join workpackage wp on wp.ixworkpackage =prwpxref.ixworkpackage
            left join workpackageactivityxref wpactxref on              wpactxref.ixworkpackage=wp.ixworkpackage
            left join activity act on act.ixactivity=wpactxref.ixactivity
          </Joins>
          <WhereClause>
            cu.fStatus=1 AND pr.fActive=1 AND pr.fDeleted=0 AND wp.fStatus=1 AND act.fStatus=1
          </WhereClause>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of `LEFT JOIN`, in the right part you have NULL when not joined.

Try this:

```
cu.fStatus=1
        AND (pr.fActive=1 OR pr.fActive IS NULL)
        AND (pr.fDeleted=0 OR pr.fDeleted IS NULL)
        AND ...
```

Answer (score 3):

try to put other conditions like (Where clause pr.fActive=1...) with it' relative **left join** clauses by using **AND**

Example...

**LEFT JOIN tblprogram  pr ON cuprxref.ixprogram = pr.ixprogram AND pr.fActive=1 AND pr.fDeleted=0**

Hope, this will help.

Answer (score 2):

Check this in Where Clause:

```
 cu.fStatus=1 OR ( pr.fActive=1 AND pr.fDeleted=0 AND wp.fStatus=1 AND act.fStatus=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you try with nested queries:

something like this,

```
SELECT finalMap.ixCustomer,finalMap.ixprogram, finalMap.ixWorkPackage,
FROM customer t
left outer join
(SELECT t.ixCustomer,cpRef.ixprogram, cpRef.ixWorkPackage
 FROM customerprogramxref t
left outer join
(SELECT pRef.ixprogram, pRef.ixWorkPackage FROM tblprogram pr
left outer join
(SELECT t.ixprogram,w.ixWorkPackage FROM programworkpackagexref t
left outer join
(SELECT wpa.ixWorkPackage FROM workpackage w
left outer join
(SELECT wpactxref.ixWorkPackage FROM workpackageactivityxref wpactxref
left outer join (SELECT t.ixactivity FROM activity t where t.fStatus=1) act
on act.ixactivity=wpactxref.ixactivity) wpa on w.ixworkpackage =wpa.ixworkpackage
where w.fStatus=1) w  on t.ixWorkPackage = w.ixWorkPackage) pRef
on pr.ixprogram = pRef.ixprogram
where pr.fActive=1  AND pr.fDeleted=0)cpRef
on t.ixprogram=cpRef.ixprogram)finalMap
on t.ixCustomer=finalMap.ixCustomer
where t.fStatus=1;
```

Comment: I was trying with the nested query only .. It will work but the execution time will be more